# Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app that writes a waiting list in the firebase realtime databse, but when I try to run this simple bit of code, I get this error (Note- I'm running this on web):

```
class FirebaseMethods {
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

  void createPartyWaiting(String partyCode, String partyHostName) async {
    partyCode = partyCode.trim();
    DataSnapshot data = await database.ref("e").get();
    print(data.value);
  }
}
```

and i'm calling it as-

```
await FirebaseMethods().createPartyWaiting("PartyCode123", "Adam");
```

But when I call it, I get this error-

```
Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com
    at Re (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-database.js:1:22344)
    at Ws (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-database.js:1:148180)
    at au (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-database.js:1:166314)
    at K.xu.INTERNAL.registerComponent.Y.setServiceProps.Reference [as instanceFactory] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-database.js:1:187315)
```

I'm initializing the web like this (I've censored the actual values)-

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (kIsWeb) {
    Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "apikey",
            authDomain: "authDomain",
            projectId: "projectId",
            storageBucket: "storageBucket",
            messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
            appId: "appId"));
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I've also found out that there's this optional arguement to the initilaziation method-

[image]

But after adding my databaseUrl here, I got this error-

```
Error: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:53659/dart_sdk.js:5063:11)
at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp (http://localhost:53659/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:248:27)
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: did you add JSON in your project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the flutter and firebase project with a new app id, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has used `$ flutterfire configure` to configure firebase to your flutter project as shown in [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/#generating-firebase-options) before adding Realtime Database, you will have to run the command again to reconfigure your project or add "databaseURL" to the FirebaseOptions in your `lib/firebase_options.dart`.

Your `lib/firebase_options.dart` should look something like this:

```
// inside lib/firebase_options.dart

// ...

static const FirebaseOptions web = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: '...',
    appId: '...',
    messagingSenderId: '...',
    projectId: 'project-id',
    authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://your-database-id.firebasedatabase.app', // IMPORTANT!
    storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
    measurementId: '...',
);

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're configuring your Firebase project (for web) by passing the configuration data to `Firebase.initializeApp`, you should also include the URL for your database there:

```
Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "apikey",
        authDomain: "authDomain",
        databaseURL: "the URL for your database", // 
        projectId: "projectId",
        storageBucket: "storageBucket",
        messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
        appId: "appId"));
```

You can find this URL in your browser by going to the [Realtime Database panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/) in the Firebase console:

[image]

---

I'm not sure why the `databaseURL` doesn't show in your auto-complete though, as I have it in all of my Dart configs (most of which are generated by the [FlutterFire CLI](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli)).

If entering the `databaseURL` manually gives an error message, I recommend checking if you're on the latest version of the libraries (although I don't recall this ever not being present).